# How to log django requests into the same file as the other django log messages (i.e., not in nginx-access.log) when in a production environment?

Tags: django, nginx, logging

In development, all logs are in one file because I'm using runserver, the dev server provided by django. My django logs contain the actual request (e.g., `GET /api/user/register`) along with my usual INFO and ERROR log messages.  This is exactly what I want.

When I go into production I use django with nginx.
The requests are now separated into the nginx-access.log file, and my django logs no longer contain the request.  As in, there is now no `GET /api/user/register` .

How do I keep the requests in the django log in production just like the used to be during development?  I want it all in one file.  It's ok if nginx-access.log keeps an additional copy of the requests.

I realize the convention is to keep the access records separate, but it's helpful to me when I know immediately what api call the user made.

Any hints?  Do I alter django settings.py or my nginx configuration? Thank you!

Comment: You can configure your wsgi-server to log requests.